# GPS is working the whole time even after getting a location

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, locationlistener

I am developing an app that uses the gps which runs until app is in service. My GPS wakes up after 5 mins and gets the location then its symbol stops blinking and becomes invisible in almost all devices (Sony xperia, Samsung tab, Htc WildFire, Motorola photon) but not in Motorola Defy and Samsung Ace, which consume huge battery power. GPS gets a fix and becomes stable and visible the whole time. The way the GPS of these devices work (Moto Defy and Samsung Ace) is different. Look at my code:

```
long _listenerWakeUpTimeInterval=1000*60*5;**  //5 minutes
_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, _listenerWakeUpTimeInterval, 300, locationListener);
```

The GPS of all devices wake up after 5 minutes but the GPS of these two devices (Moto Defy and Samsung Ace) calls the `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` method every 300 meters. The time matters not for these two devices. When I travel fast (in a car) this distance is covered in a few minutes (1 or 2 minutes). So I get a call on `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` method. And in these devices the GPS is always fixed, static and visible. I don't want to call `locationManager.removesupdates` methods every time when the GPS gets a fix. I only cal this method in `onDestroy()` of service. So please tell why the GPS of these two devices behaves differently from other devices, and how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem.I use `AlarmManager`(repeating alarm after each 5 minutes) to register gps and then I run my Gps for  30 seconds and unregister Gps .If I got call in `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` then I unregister Gps in this method.otherwise(If i don't get new location)  I unregister Gps through handler after 30 seconds.When I need Gps again I follow the same process.By this way my Gps works max 30 seconds not for whole the time until service run.

Answer (score 2):

If you read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29), it says:

> *minTime: the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.*

So it is only a suggestion and the implementation can ignore it.

My proposal is to use `AlertManager` to schedule your service each 5 minutes, and then in the service payload, request a single fix calling `requestSingleUpdate`. This will save battery. The drawback is that the GPS chip takes some time until it receives the satellites signal, about 30 seconds to 1 minute in good conditions (Time To First Fix, or TTFF). After serving all pending requests, it goes cold again. So in the next service execution, the TTFF could be as high as in the previous iteration, I guess. (Unless you use NETWORK_PROVIDER, but then the accuracy is lower).